# Random variable measurable with respect to stopping time sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, stopping-times, measurable-functions

I want to prove that given two ($\mathcal{F}_t$)-stopping times $\tau$ and $\nu$ and a $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable random variable $Y$

\begin{equation}
Y \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau \leq \nu \}} \text{ is } \mathcal{F}_\nu\text{-measurable}.
\end{equation}
Recall that $\mathcal{F}_\tau = \{ A \in \mathcal{F} : A \cap \{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t\geq 0 \}$.

The proof I have come up with goes as follows:

Let $B \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R})$ and $t\geq 0$.

\begin{equation}
\{Y \in B\} \cap \{ \tau \leq \nu\} \cap \{ \nu \leq t\} = \Big(\{Y \in B\} \cap \{ \tau \leq t\}\Big) \cap \Big(\{ \tau \leq \nu\} \cap \{ \nu \leq t\} \Big)
\end{equation}

Now $\{Y \in B\} \cap \{ \tau \leq t\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_t$ because $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable. $\{ \tau \leq \nu\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}_{\tau \wedge \nu} \subset \mathcal{F}_{\nu}$ and the right part is therefore in $\mathcal{F}_t$, too. This gives us that $\{Y \in B\} \cap \{ \tau \leq \nu\} \cap \{ \nu \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ which completes the proof.

Is the above proof correct? I feel a bit weird about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks okay (... though you forgot to define $X$). To make the proof of measurability complete, you also need to verify that $\{X \in B\} \cap \{\tau>\nu\} \cap \{\nu \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$... but that's the easy part.

Comment: Thanks, the $X$ was supposed to be a $Y$ still. It was a typo. I changed it.

Comment: I find verifying $\{Y \in B\} \cap \{ \tau > \nu\} \cap \{ \nu \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ actually to be more difficult... Is there an easy way without much calculation?

Comment: Answering my own question and looking for someone to confirm:
Wouldn't I only need to verify that $\{0 \in B\} \cap \{ \tau > \nu \} \in \mathcal{F}_\nu$ which is obvious since $\{ 0 \in B \} = \emptyset$ or $\Omega$ and $\{ \tau > \nu \} \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau \wedge \nu} \subset \mathcal{F}_{\nu}$. Does that suffice?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply to your question But yes, that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!